# How do I make links clickable in .log files?

Tags: linux, python, url

I have a python script that logs URLs to be generated on the fly.  I'd like to be able to `cat logfile.log` so that I can see the output of the log then be able to click those links rather than copy/pasting them into my browser window.  Is this possible if I make a shell script or even better if I just run it through cat/head/tail?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: I think I'm using Bash to view files

Answer (score 1):

To make links clickable from **.log** files, you need to create a logfile as **.html** file format. As python logging module inspired by **log4j** . There is an **HTMLLayout** in log4j logging module.

But to make this happen, you have to well aware of python formatting and also learn how to write your own formatting. If you already know how to write your own formatting then it would be easier for you to format a .log file to a .html file. I've found the thread form where you can get the idea about formatting logfile in HTML, or colouring a logfile output. Please visit the this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039343/python-logging-how-to-create-logfile-as-html)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat urls.log | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | sort | uniq > myurls.txt
```

And the output would be :

```
pi@berry:~s$ cat urls.html | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[\da-z./?A-Z0-9\D=_-]*" | uniq
http://schema.org/WebPage
http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en
http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en
https://play.google.com/?hl=en
http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1
http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/
http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en
http://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/project/the-holocaust?utm_source=google
https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550
```

- Explanation:

  - grep -E : is the same as egrep
  - grep -o : only outputs what has been grepped
  - (http|https) : is an either / or
  - a-z : is all lower case
  - A-Z : is all uper case
  - . : is dot
  - \?: is ?
  - *: is repeat the [...] group
  - uniq : will remove any duplicates

Put it in a bash

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '---------------------------------------------'
echo 'Now starting'
echo '---------------------------------------------'


while read p;
  do   x-www-browser "$p";
done < myurls.txt
```

The bash should open a new tab for each URL
Sources :

- [How to use grep and cut in script to obtain website URLs from an
  HTML file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181258)
- [Ubuntu commands to open URL's in graphic interface with
  prefered browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19919/command-to-open-a-url)
- [More on XDG-OPEN](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

Comment: upvoted because let's be frank here, that's awesome and I'll probably use it ....but what I was after was a way to make links clickable in the terminal output.  I store my files as .log files I tried to run them through and even change them to <a href*></a> but that just pipes out the entire string, but not as clickable links

Comment: Well, there are a lot of way's, please next time specify exactly what you are searching for :) - I gave you a way of CAT'ing into log, pulling logs and displaying in Terminal, then you just CTRL click ( if not under OS X ). As i Read arround, It all depends on the Terminal emulator, for example XFCE has ctrl + LEFT click or Middle button, for normally Ubuntu vanilla terminal ctrl + right click as far as i remembered, so you just need a neat terminal emulator on your OS X which allows you to do some behavioural modifications :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a bit more googling gave me the answer I was looking for:

[Taken From this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2338765/2226328)

Tl;dr - depends on your terminal emulator. I'm using OSX.  This works for me:

> **Before OSX Lion:**
>
> <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+double-click on a URL in Terminal.app and it will open in
>   the default program.
>
> **OSX Lion:**
>
> <kbd>cmd</kbd>+double-click (otherwise you will enter fullscreen mode).